# Dual Monitor: HDMI no signal, not recognized in Ubuntu

Tags: ati, monitor, hdmi, radeon

brand new Asus VE247H monitor, connected by VGA, is not getting recognized in Ubuntu 11.04.

Monitor Preferences does not recognize a second monitor ('Unknown'). ATI Catalyst Control Administrative does not either (I can add an external monitor, but nothing actually happens).

The monitor itself does not recognize Ubuntu either and switches into standby after displaying the message 'HDMI no signal'.

Running dual install with Windows 7 on Dell Inspiron, 64-bit install, Graphics Card Radeon HD 5000 und driver ATI (fglrx). Laptop and monitor per se work together on Windows 7 (which my brother uses). So the problem is a Ubuntu compatibility one.

Any suggestions? I always work with Ubuntu, I don't want to have to send the monitor back because Ubuntu is making a fuss.

Comment: Don't know if this still affects you but I had this exact problem (with a different monitor). I was able to get everything to work by using a DVI cable instead of HDMI.